# Best practice to learn English

Tags: learning

How should I start to improve my English?

I know this may closed as off-topic, but I just need some clear steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a stack exchange site just for english language learners.  As you come up with questions, you can ask them there:  http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: (1) locate several native English speakers. (2) make friends with them. (3) spend time with them and pay attention. (4) talk like your native friends talk. (5) if possible, move to where English is spoken natively; that makes (1-4) much easier. That is the best practice. There are others that don't usually work as well, too.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for your advice, mostly can't apply in my case since I live in non English native language, but I'm gonna try to apply your advices

Comment: As a non-native, I advise you to read good literature as if your life depended on it. And for entertainment, restrict yourself exclusively to watching English-language movies and TV shows.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction I'm trying this nowadays, but still can't understand most of words when speaking rapidly, I think I need some more time or do you have some advice for that?

Comment: @Maythux: It won't happen overnight, but it will happen. Keep a dictionary handy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because duplicates have been closed as off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth where is the duplicate link?

Comment: 'Improving written English and Grammar [closed]' for a start. Please do not ask for others. And you had a strong suspicion that this was well off-topic.

Comment: I say it may be off-topic since i thought it would be primary opinion based or too-broad

Comment: Immersion. or YouTube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be hardly a reasonable answer for you, as it depends on your educational background, on how long you have studied English and what level you have reached and what you aim at for what reasons. All these things are unknown to us. Actually you have to find your own way. There are effective ways and ineffectives ones, but I think they are a bit different for each individual person.

Don't look for a best method, try to find out what ways are effective and which ones aren't. And check if you can handle the tools for studying a language (dictionaries and grammars) and if you understand the language of grammars (grammar terms).

Answer (score 2):

Try to think in English! It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Listen to English,
2. Listen more,
3. Listen more,
4. Speak in English.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, I'm afraid. Most of the questions here come from people who have tried this method already, and found it less than ideal. Writing is not the language. Speech is the language, and you have to be able to **hear** it, even to follow the grammar rules. For one instance out of thousands, _a_ versus _an_ depends on sound, not writing.

Comment: I'm doing that mostly, but still feel I miss something, I need more

Answer (score 0):

I would say definitely start off by speaking in English. Try a direct approach and link ideas and images directly to the English words you are thinking of, rather than using a middleman such as translation of your first language or picturing how the words are written in English - this will enable you able to speak more fluently and to express your ideas well.
If you get stuck, think about how a young child might learn their first language and mimic the process. I have to stress that this is of course only my opinion of the most effective way of learning a less-familiar language.